# Longest substrings that occur at least twice

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the longest substrings that occur at least twice. The code below gave me timeout. What is wrong with it? How can it be improved? They state that the text should consist of uppercase latin letters, but that doesn't affect it in any way.

ABAAAABAB should return AAA.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    char ch;
    unordered_map<char, Node*> children;
    vector<int> indexes;
    Node(char c) :ch(c) {}
};

size_t maxLen = 0;
string maxStr = "";

void insertInSuffixTree(Node* root, string& str, int index, string originalSuffix, size_t level = 0)
{
    root->indexes.push_back(index);

    if (root->indexes.size() > 1 && maxLen < level)
    {
        maxLen = level;
        maxStr = originalSuffix.substr(0, level);
    }

    if (str.length() == level) return;

    Node* child;
    if (root->children.count(str[level]) == 0) {
        child = new Node(str[level]);
        root->children[str[level]] = child;
    }
    else {
        child = root->children[str[level]];
    }

    insertInSuffixTree(child, str, index, originalSuffix, level + 1);
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    string str;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cin >> str;
        Node* root = new Node('@');

        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
            string s = str.substr(i);
            insertInSuffixTree(root, s, i, s);
        }

        cout << maxStr << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why not ABA?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, that's from the conditions.

Comment: What conditions? ABA occurs twice isn't it?

Comment: Don't copy entire string without first symbol when pass to `insertInSuffixTree`, pass string by reference and pass current index, so `insertInSuffixTree` would have linear complexity. Also you can read about Ukkonen's algorithm to build suffix tree ever more faster.

Comment: @fas, can you show an example on what you mean

Comment: What is the purpose of `num`?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, you can ignore it. It's the count of tests you can do.

Comment: That is wrong: you have multiple tests and a single answer.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov, corrected it but the problem still persists.

Comment: `level` seems to represent current symbol index, so `void insertInSuffixTree(Node* root, string str, int index, string originalSuffix, int level = 0)` -> `void insertInSuffixTree(Node* root, string& str, int index, string originalSuffix, int level = 0)`, `str.empty()` -> `str.length() == level`, all `str[0]` -> `str[level]` and `insertInSuffixTree(child, str.substr(1), index, originalSuffix, level + 1);` -> `insertInSuffixTree(child, str, index, originalSuffix, level + 1);`

Comment: I agree with the test of advisors: don't create copies of the string (.substr method copies a substring).

Comment: @fas, still timeout. I edited the question with the changes.